# Charging fees only to the secondary receivers of a chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Looking through the Docs, it says that:

> SECONDARYONLY – Secondary receivers pay all fees (use only for chained payments with **one** secondary receiver) *(emphasis mine)*

Is this a typo in their docs? Can you only use this with a single secondary receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not a typo. Using an Adaptive Payment Chained Payment, the secondary receiver can be at least 1 receiver and 1 primary receiver. As documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), you can have at most one primary receiver and ***1-9 secondary receivers***.But if Secondary receiver nee to pay for the fees, the secondary receiver must have exactly 2 receivers only.

Comment: So its at *at least* one secondary receiver. Gotcha. Why does [the PayRequest](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) specify a maximum of 5 recipients?

Comment: I believe now is updated to 9 secondary receiver. Just tested it. ;)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `SECONDARYONLY` only works with exactly two receivers.